# Python - fetchmail to execute command based on email subject

Tags: python, grep, pipeline, fetchmail

I am wanting to control a remote system based on an email inbox.   For example, a email account with a message in it, with a subject of "Start motor".
I have fetchmail retrieving one message and outputting it into file.  Is there an option to just get a message subject with fetchmail?

I am trying to parse or grep the output file to search for the subject "Start motor".  I was trying to pipe the grep but I do not see an option to True/False if the text string is found?

Assuming the text string is found, I want to GPIO.output(18,GPIO.HIGH)

Comment: Read: [python.org/3/library/mailbox.html#examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mailbox.html#examples). The first example should be fine for you.

Comment: What I understand from reading the mailbox spec is that it is for mail that is on the drive.  I am referencing email that is on a GMail mailbox.

Comment: Read: [pop3-lib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/poplib.html#)

Comment: A working example: [read-email-pop3](https://pythonspot.com/read-email-pop3/)